# Formula causing .xlsx to need repair on open

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, epplus

I'm generating an .xlsx file using the EPPlus library.

I create several worksheets, each with multiple rows. Some rows have a cell reference in column J which I am inserting using the following:

```
for (int i = 2; i < rowCount; i++)    // start on row 2 (header)
{
    var formula = GetCellRefFormula(i);
    worksheet.Cells[$"J{i}"].Formula = formula;
}

// save worksheet/workbook

private string GetCellRefFormula(int i)
{
    return $"\"Row \"&ROW(D{i})"
}
```

When I open the workbook I get the following errors:

```
Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part
Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet7.xml part
```

The errors are certainly caused by the string returned from GetCellRefFormula(), if I don't set these formulas or GetCellRefFormula simply returns an empty string, I get no errors.

I have also tried setting the formula to have an equals sign in front, with the same result.

```
private string GetCellRefFormula(int i)
{
    return $"=\"Row \"&ROW(D{i})"
}
```

Should I be setting the formula field like this?

Is there a way to see specifically which formulas are incorrect in the Excel repair log?

As far as I can see it only gives the errors I've copied above.

Comment: What does the `$` do?

Comment: @Ernie its C#5 syntax for formatting a string, like string.Format("{0}", i)

Comment: Sorry, I should have probably worded that better.  Yes, assuming its the string.Format eq your `getCellRefFormula`  is missing the `int` in its declaration.  If that is just a typo your code runs fine for me.  Maybe post more of your code on how your are creating and saving the `Package`.